# Why does the crypt() function not have a memory leak?

Tags: c, crypt

From [crypt(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt):

```
char *crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
```

**Return Value**:
A pointer to the encrypted password is returned. On error, `NULL` is returned.

Since the return value is unknown unless key and salt is given, this should be dynamically allocated memory, but valgrind doesn't agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the man page:

> The return value points to static data
>   whose content is overwritten by each call.

So this means it's not dynamically allocated - it's a single static allocation (just like a global variable).

Answer (score 3):

From the page you linked:

> The returned value points to the encrypted password, a series of 13 printable ASCII characters (the first two characters represent the salt itself). The return value points to static data whose content is overwritten by each call.